# how to handle the data encoding issue while copying the data from CSV file to parquet using Azure copy activity?

Tags: character-encoding, parquet, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file that I wanted to convert to the parquet the CSV file contains the value **Querý** in one column

So I am using use copy activity from the azure data factory and converting to the parquet but I get the value as **QueryÃ½**. I don't find any enoding option in the sink. I have seen a few documentation but everything says about the CSV file ending. Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set the encoding of parquet in Azure Data Factory.

I created a pipeline to test and it can work fine.

[image]

Here are some advice for you to troubleshoot:

1. Make sure the encoding of your csv file is correct.

[image]

2. Make sure your schema of Parquet is correct.

[image]